# How to change fontFamily when user changed language?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an app support RTL and LTR language and I'm using fontFamily from xml to change fonts for some text. The problem is that when I set the font family at xml and choose an Arabic font

> android:fontFamily="@font/sans_arabic_bold"

It looks nice but when user changes language to LTR this Arabic font will not work for other language. So how can I solve that?

Comment: create two folder in the resource folder font-ltr and font-rtl

Comment: @JavadShakouri That assumes the only RTL font he wants to support is Arabic-  not Hebrew, Urdu, Farsi, etc.  Unlikely to be the case.  He's probably better off changing it in code in onCreate.

Comment: Changing the font is a very heavy task for the processor. I've used this method and done so well

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy and the steps are to get current local or current language for the application
with this code

`var local = if (LanguageSetting.getLanguage(context).toString()=="ar") "ar" else "en"`
now i have current language and i can set the font file based on it

`var font_family = if local=="ar") R.fonts.arabicfont else R.fonts.otherlanguagefont`